# Can I attach an action to a buttonclick?

Tags: javascript, html, button

If i have a button, can I attach an action to it to perform server side processing, or does it have to be wrapped in a form?

For example

```
<button type="submit" onClick="listco_directory_contents.js"> List </button>
```

Can this be made to work, or is a form required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can yes but if your aiming to do server side processes i recommend the jquery way.

```
<!--this button uses javascript-->
<input type="button" onclick="myfunction()" value="button"/>

<!--this button uses jquery-->
<input type="button" id="myfunction" value="button"/>

<script>
//javascript function using the onclick event
function myfunction(){
    alert("an action");
    // or any other function u wish to 
    // do once the button is click
}

//jquery using the id of the button
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#myfunction").click(function(){
        alert("another action");
        // or any other function u wish to 
        // do once the button is click
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a `type="submit"` if it's not in a form, there is nothing to submit. What you can do, is having a `<button id="myButton">`, then attach an event to it:

```
var myButton = document.selectElementById('myButton');
myButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  /* do something cool */
}, false);
```

And the "do something cool" could be an Ajax request so you send data to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just include the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="listco_directory_contents.js"></script>
```

and then call whatever function you need from there:

```
<button onClick="exampleFunction()"> List </button>
```

Or in case you want to do server side processing with php you can do simply:

```
<button onClick="$.post('http://example.com/index.php');"> List </button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function(){
 $(':submit').on('click',function(){
  alert('hi');
 })
})
```

also can be type=submit

```
$(function(){
 $('input[type="submit"]').on('click',function(){
  alert('hi');
 })
})
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/cuvs167t/)**